# how detect vim enable certain feature? such as set nu

Tags: vim

I wanna a function to detect whether VIM has enabled 'set nu' feature.
How do I make the script?
Kindly indicate me which resource in 'help' if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:h 'number'` will bring it up in help.

```
:let x = &number
" x will be 1 if set number is on
" x will be 0 if set number is off
:echo &number  "will print value
```

Answer (score 6):

To determine whether [`'number'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27number%27) is set, use the `?` to query:

```
:set nu?
```

To determine from where it was set last:

```
:verbose set nu?
```

For more information on options, see:

- [`:help set-option`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#options)
- [`:help :verbose`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3averbose)

Comment: sorry, I just can mark one answer. Your answer is also what I need. Thanks very much.